# "\Logs was unexpected at this time" while starting logstash in my windows machine

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I Don't know why this happens[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQHLZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer code than image in your question :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

logstash does not support spaces in the path to the install directory (that includes "\Program Files (x86)"). And I get that spaces in the install directory path have been absolutely standard on Windows for many years. Elastic do not support them.

```
\logstash-7.16.3\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar was unexpected at this time.
```

Is a very common variant of this.